# masonry/mosaic style image grid - size, spacing troubles

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, jquery-masonry

My homepage features a masonry/mosaic style image grid that is giving me some trouble re: spacing.
Ideally, there should be a 10px gap between all images(though they should be flush with the edge of the `div`). For the most part, I believe I have this set up correctly, however the between space is off and the bottom row of images is shifted well to the right. What am I missing to repair this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMac5/)

Added Syntax highlighting for code

```html
<nav>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/165x309"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x309"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
        </div>
    </nav><!-- end nav -->
```

```css
nav {
    width: 940px;
}
nav a {
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
    width: 465px;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 149px;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 149px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 165px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 288px;
    height: 309px;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(4) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're going for here (how is this a nav?) and I don't think I would have structured the code this way.  But, you need to keep in mind that the width of your columns (divs) need to include the margins on your containing objects.  Also, you were missing your nav div:nth-child(2) column definition in the css.
This works, but I don't love it:

```
nav {
    width: 945px;
}
nav a {
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
    width: 470px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 149px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 149px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 470px;
    float:left;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 165px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 288px;
    height: 309px;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(4) {
    width: 465px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/HytkQ/)

I'd prefer to see something along these lines

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#" class="wide short"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
            <a href="#" class="wide short"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#" class="narrow tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/165x309"></a>
            <a href="#" class="med tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x309"></a>
            <a href="#" class="wide tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
            <a href="#" class="wide tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
        </div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 960px;
}
a {
    float: left;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 475px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.col .wide {
    width: 465px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.col .narrow {
    width: 165px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.col .med {
    width: 288px;
    height: 309px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;

}

.col .short {
    height: 149px;
}
.col .tall {
    height: 309px;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/gkQbC/)
I don't think the heights are actually necessary, but I tossed them in.

To have the big images appear below (option 1 of my comment below)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        <a href="#" class="wide short"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
        <a href="#" class="wide short"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x149"></a>
        <a href="#" class="wide tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <a href="#" class="narrow tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/165x309"></a>
        <a href="#" class="med tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x309"></a>
        <a href="#" class="wide tall"><img src="http://placehold.it/465x309"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/VCfXD/)

Comment: Barbara, thank you for such a thorough answer. This looks great, however the bottom row (the 465x309 blocks) are aligned vertically instead of horizontally. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Well, that makes more sense :)
You have a couple of options.  You could put the 1st big one in the 1st column and the 2nd in the 2nd column.  Or you could add 2 more divs (new columns that live under the others) and place them in there.  I'll add it to the answer